# How to insert cell text from one cell into an ImportRange Function

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, importrange

[image: Google Sheet with Column B as a link and Column C with an ImportRange Function]

Hello! so I have an issue where I am trying to do is have multiple functions in C, D, and E where a link is required. Instead of copying and pasting the link inside all the functions in specific locations several times, I am hoping to have to only insert it once in Column B, and then having that link insert itself into specific locations per that row. Is there any way to do that, an app or function that I can use to make this faster?

Answer (score -1):

```
=IMPORTRANGE(INDIRECT("A4"), "Sheet1!A1:B2")
```

[image]